# Possible reasons for error: "The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null"

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I'm getting a report of errors from a production system. I don't have easy access to the production system. I will get all the data that I need for it in due course, but what I'm trying to do is expedite the process of resolution of this issue. I'm trying to eliminate as much guesswork as possible.

The error I'm getting this this:

> Extended Properties: Exception - System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   cast to value type 'Decimal' failed
>   because the materialized value is
>   null. Either the result type's generic
>   parameter or the query must use a
>   nullable type.

The code where the error is happening is this:

```
IQueryable<AccountStatusModel> result = from d in Context.Debtors
    where // Condition here
    select new AccountStatusModel
    {
         // All of the below are decimal in the AccountStatusModel
         // and all of them are decimal NOT NULL in the database
         NotYetDue = d.sometable.dbcurrent,
         DueThisMonth = d.sometable.dbprd1bal,
         Overdue = d.sometable.dbprd2bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd3bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd4bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd5bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd6bal,
         PaymentRecievedNotAllocated = d.sometable.dbunalloc,
         OutstandingOrders = d.dmoutordval ?? 0,
         TotalBalance = d.sometable.dbcurrent
                + d.sometable.dbprd1bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd2bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd3bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd4bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd5bal
                + d.sometable.dbprd6bal
                + d.sometable.dbunalloc
                + (d.dmoutordval ?? 0),
         CreditLimit = d.dmcredlim,
         LastPayment = d.dmvallastpaid,

         // Some other properties here
         // ....
    };
```

Before someone comments on the field names, assume that these are fake names. =)
Note, that all the database fields being queried are NOT NULL.

I cannot reproduce this error in dev environment.

I think, that the reason this error happening in PROD, is because somehow, among the fields that are being queried, one is marked as NULL. I have no quick way of checking this, but I eventually will.

My question for now is this: Could there be any other reason for this error? Is it possible to get this error if the query is as above, and the fields are indeed NOT NULLs. (And why?) If it is possible could you please provide an example how.

Please only answer if you are positive that you are right, i.e. I need something stronger, than "I *think* this is so".

Comment: "Please only answer if you are positive that you are right" - not a good idea. You'll want people to suggest things to try, surely.

Comment: Do you have multithreading going on?

Comment: @GregC It's a web application

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: thank you for your input, you do have a point. Suggestions are welcome!!! It's just that I'm fairly sure (on common sense grounds) that I'm right, and it's unlikely that there is another reason for this error. I want to hear from someone who is even more sure than me, if this makes sense. This question is not practical, it's theoretical, although it comes from practical background. I will easily resolve it *practically* in a few day. However I might never find out from the theory perspective if the scenario described is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I suspected in my comment to GregC answer, the problem was with a join. The schema turned out to be correct. However ever the query that I cited, can return nulls if "sometable" does not have a record for related "Debtors" record. I this case d.sometable.Anything will be null. Because L2E coalesces NULLS it does not complain that d.sometable is null simply returning null for d.sometable.Anything instead.

So this how and why.

Comment: Changed the type of properties on `AccountStatusModel` from `decimal` to `decimal?`

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good.  The key here is the word "materialized," which implies that the exception happened when hydrating a table cell with a DBNull in it.

Comment: In SQL there are ways to get NULL in a column, even if the column marked NOT NULL. For example when you do outer join, if the condition does not get matched, you will get all nulls on one part, regardless of what is in your schema for that columns. In the case of my query there no obvious outer join or anything else that would lead of getting nulls from DB from non null columns. Can you think of anything?

Comment: You could bring in some database guru eyes on this problem with an appropriate tag on the question.